# When does osmosis stop?

Tags: physical-chemistry, solutions, osmosis

In the figure given below:-

[image]

Since only solvent particles can  move through semipermeable membrane, if we manage to keep pressure on both the containers equal say by keeping weights, will osmosis go on till pure solvent container reaches zero volume?

Comment: It depends on the geometry of the vessels. If tall enough, osmotic pressure will be balanced by hydrostatic pressure difference.

Comment: Osmosis phenomena produces a height difference which tends to a maximum ℎ
h. If both solvent and solution are at atmospheric pressure, this maximum is such that ℎ is equal to $1$ atm, for a $1$M solution. This height is also proportional the concentration of the solution.

Comment: @Poutnik I actually meant that if I apply and keep changing pressure on the other (solvent) container as well such that pressure remains equal on both the containers, will the osmosis take place?

Comment: If the membrane pressure difference (= external pressure difference  + hydrostatic pressure difference) balances the osmotic pressure, the net osmosis is zero.

Comment: @Poutnik Thanks I understood that. Just wanted like confirmation that osmosis will keep going on if there difference in membrane pressure difference  and osmotic pressure, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $H_l$ = Hydrostatic pressure in solution jar
Let $O_l$ = Osmotic pressure in solution jar
Let $P_l$ = Pressure from the weight applied to the solution jar

Let $H_s$ = Hydrostatic pressure in solvent jar
Let $O_s$ = Osmotic pressure in solvent jar
Let $P_s$ = Pressure from the weight applied to the solvent jar

Osmosis will take place until ...
$H_l + O_s + P_l = H_s + O_l + P_s$

We know $O_s = 0$ and $P_l = P_s$. So the equation for when the osmosis will stop simplifies to ...

$H_l = O_l + H_s$